# How to get the upload file location in Gradio?

Tags: gradio

I am using Gradio to build the UI. I am using the following code to upload a file.

```
import gradio as gr

def upload_file(files):
    file_paths = [file.name for file in files]
    return file_paths

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    file_output = gr.File()
    opt = gr.Label()
    upload_button = gr.UploadButton("Click to Upload a File", file_types=["image", "video"], file_count="multiple")
    upload_button.upload(upload_file, upload_button, file_output)

demo.launch()
```

How to get the file location in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but for anyone else who is dealing with file uploads when using **Gradio** I have found the following function (and variations of it) that makes use of the `shutil` library infinitely useful!

```py
def process_file(fileobj):
    path = "/home/ubuntu/temps/" + os.path.basename(fileobj)
    shutil.copyfile(fileobj.name, path)
    # now you can process the file at path as needed, e.g:
    # do_something_to_file(path)
```

Without doing this, I found I had a lot of issues treating the file initially uploaded to Gradio as a `tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper` object. I found I was encountering a lot of permission issues and it was hard to do everything I wanted with the object and the `tempfile` library.

This new method with `shutil` gives you complete control over a permanent file object, and if you need to delete it afterwards just add in the code to do so when you're done.

In the context of using this with Gradio, it would work in a simple example as follows:

```py
import gradio as gr
import os
import shutil

def process_file(fileobj):
    path = "/home/ubuntu/temps/" + os.path.basename(fileobj)  #NB*
    shutil.copyfile(fileobj.name, path)
    return do_something_to_file(path)

demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=process_file,
    inputs=[
        "file",
    ],
    outputs="text"
)
demo.launch(server_name='0.0.0.0')
```

*NB:* I am doing this on an Ubuntu instance, obviously please modify path name accordingly for your operating system and needs. If you have issues with this method check that you and your python script have permission to write to whichever directory you specify in your path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
import gradio as gr

def process_file(fileobj): 
    file_path = fileobj.name 
    return do_something(file_path)

demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=process_file,
    inputs=[
        "file",
    ],
    outputs="text"
)

demo.launch(server_name='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Below code works. Hope code is clear now

```
import gradio as gr    
import shutil    
import os    

def upload_file(file):    
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = "./data"    
    if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):    
        os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)    
    shutil.copy(file, UPLOAD_FOLDER)    
    gr.Info("File Uploaded!!!")    

with gr.Blocks() as demo:    
    gr.Markdown(    
        """    
        # Welcome to MyApp    
        """)    
    upload_button = gr.UploadButton("Click to Upload a File")    
    upload_button.upload(upload_file, upload_button)    

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    demo.launch()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please *explain* how this solve this issue at hand. Just adding "Below code works" doesn't explain anything